# Contact Form 7 - Debugging email send failres

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, errors

I am getting the red failed error when trying to send a message.

I referred to the FAQ and this is the extent of help available:

"There are really various reasons for server side problems, so I can’t explain exactly what yours is. But experiences of other users who solved their problem might be helpful for you."

Not helpful at all! I don't really want or expect someone else to solve my problem, all I want is some debugging guidance to see the error that is being produced so I can debug it myself!

How can I see the actual error that is occurring instead of the generic "failed" message?

Answer (score 2):

This is actual mail server trouble, where email cannot be sent. 
This link will useful.
http://angstrey.com/index.php/2009/04/22/how-to-send-e-mail-with-wordpress-from-godaddy-windows-hosting/

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help debug my issue. There must be something wrong somewhere - I'd prefer to try and fix it before just trying a new method of sending emails (considering I'm using Contac Form 7 on many other websites without a problem)  There must be some way to view the response headers?